# Variable scope efficiency in Java

Tags: java, scope

A quick performance/memory question:

What is better, if there even is a difference?

This

```
int x;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
 x = i;
 //do something
}
```

or this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
 int x = i;
 //do something
}
```

?

Comment: Did you try it?  There's almost certainly no difference.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Primitives, sure.  Heavyweight objects?  Less so.

Comment: If there was a difference, it would be negligible. So prefer the second one, which limits the scope of x. Tune your IO and your algorithms. Micro-optimizations like that won't have any significant impact on performance, but will have one on code readability and robustness.

Comment: -1 cause you didn't run a simple test on it to find the answer

Comment: @Makoto if you look at the second answer of the link I provided you'll see the byte codes are **exactly** the same - no difference what so ever.

Comment: @Makoto as long as the number of created objects is the same, where is defined the reference is also equally fast.

Comment: compilers nowadays are really good at optimizing code.

Comment: Any possible difference in efficiency would be so minor that if it matters you probably shouldn't be using Java in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I think they will both be the same in terms of assembly (its faster to just do a large stack push than a bunch of push pops for local variables sometimes). It will just reduce the scope of x in the second case even if they both produce the same bytecode.

Comment: How could it produce the same byte code but limit the scope?

Comment: Compilers are smart - if they see you don't use it after the loop - they'll limit the scope for you.

Comment: @JasonSperske The variable is just an offset in the stack. It limits the scope by forgetting the variable exists outside the loop.

Comment: @JasonSperske In compilers there exists environments and the concept of pushing and popping environments. Inside the loop there exists something which binds to 'x' the stack offset. Outside of it x is unknown because the environment that contained it was popped.

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly the same... defining a variable (primitive / reference) is just calculating the position where it will live (as an offset of the stack pointer). That is done by the compiler.